# Displaying author photo below title and excerpt in single post

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, wordpress-theming

I'm using the Twenty Twenty One WordPress theme and would like to add an author image below the title and the excerpt in the entry header for all the single-post pages.

Here's a photo of where I'd like the image to go:
[Image of blog post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74F8U.jpg)

I've been searching a lot on the web trying to find a solution, and I'm pretty sure I need to add some kind of code to the Functions.php section in the theme editor. But most of the solutions I find is only for either the Genesis theme framework or the GeneratePress theme framework.

Here's a copy of the Functions.php for the theme:

```
<?php

if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '5.3', '<' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/back-compat.php';
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'twenty_twenty_one_setup' ) ) {
    
    function twenty_twenty_one_setup() {

        load_theme_textdomain( 'twentytwentyone', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

        add_theme_support(
            'post-formats',
            array(
                'link',
                'aside',
                'gallery',
                'image',
                'quote',
                'status',
                'video',
                'audio',
                'chat',
            )
        );

        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 1568, 9999 );

        register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary menu', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                'footer'  => esc_html__( 'Secondary menu', 'twentytwentyone' ),
            )
        );

        add_theme_support(
            'html5',
            array(
                'comment-form',
                'comment-list',
                'gallery',
                'caption',
                'style',
                'script',
                'navigation-widgets',
            )
        );

        $logo_width  = 300;
        $logo_height = 100;

        add_theme_support(
            'custom-logo',
            array(
                'height'               => $logo_height,
                'width'                => $logo_width,
                'flex-width'           => true,
                'flex-height'          => true,
                'unlink-homepage-logo' => true,
            )
        );

        add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );

        add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' );

        add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );

        add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
        $background_color = get_theme_mod( 'background_color', 'D1E4DD' );
        if ( 127 > Twenty_Twenty_One_Custom_Colors::get_relative_luminance_from_hex( $background_color ) ) {
            add_theme_support( 'dark-editor-style' );
        }

        $editor_stylesheet_path = './assets/css/style-editor.css';

        global $is_IE;
        if ( $is_IE ) {
            $editor_stylesheet_path = './assets/css/ie-editor.css';
        }

        add_editor_style( $editor_stylesheet_path );

        add_theme_support(
            'editor-font-sizes',
            array(
                array(
                    'name'      => esc_html__( 'Extra small', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'shortName' => esc_html_x( 'XS', 'Font size', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'size'      => 16,
                    'slug'      => 'extra-small',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'      => esc_html__( 'Small', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'shortName' => esc_html_x( 'S', 'Font size', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'size'      => 18,
                    'slug'      => 'small',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'      => esc_html__( 'Normal', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'shortName' => esc_html_x( 'M', 'Font size', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'size'      => 20,
                    'slug'      => 'normal',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'      => esc_html__( 'Large', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'shortName' => esc_html_x( 'L', 'Font size', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'size'      => 24,
                    'slug'      => 'large',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'      => esc_html__( 'Extra large', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'shortName' => esc_html_x( 'XL', 'Font size', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'size'      => 40,
                    'slug'      => 'extra-large',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'      => esc_html__( 'Huge', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'shortName' => esc_html_x( 'XXL', 'Font size', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'size'      => 96,
                    'slug'      => 'huge',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'      => esc_html__( 'Gigantic', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'shortName' => esc_html_x( 'XXXL', 'Font size', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'size'      => 144,
                    'slug'      => 'gigantic',
                ),
            )
        );

        add_theme_support(
            'custom-background',
            array(
                'default-color' => 'd1e4dd',
            )
        );

        $black     = '#000000';
        $dark_gray = '#28303D';
        $gray      = '#39414D';
        $green     = '#D1E4DD';
        $blue      = '#D1DFE4';
        $purple    = '#D1D1E4';
        $red       = '#E4D1D1';
        $orange    = '#E4DAD1';
        $yellow    = '#EEEADD';
        $white     = '#FFFFFF';

        add_theme_support(
            'editor-color-palette',
            array(
                array(
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'Black', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'slug'  => 'black',
                    'color' => $black,
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'Dark gray', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'slug'  => 'dark-gray',
                    'color' => $dark_gray,
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'Gray', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'slug'  => 'gray',
                    'color' => $gray,
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'Green', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'slug'  => 'green',
                    'color' => $green,
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'Blue', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'slug'  => 'blue',
                    'color' => $blue,
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'Purple', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'slug'  => 'purple',
                    'color' => $purple,
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'Red', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'slug'  => 'red',
                    'color' => $red,
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'Orange', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'slug'  => 'orange',
                    'color' => $orange,
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'Yellow', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'slug'  => 'yellow',
                    'color' => $yellow,
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'White', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'slug'  => 'white',
                    'color' => $white,
                ),
            )
        );

        add_theme_support(
            'editor-gradient-presets',
            array(
                array(
                    'name'     => esc_html__( 'Purple to yellow', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'gradient' => 'linear-gradient(160deg, ' . $purple . ' 0%, ' . $yellow . ' 100%)',
                    'slug'     => 'purple-to-yellow',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'     => esc_html__( 'Yellow to purple', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'gradient' => 'linear-gradient(160deg, ' . $yellow . ' 0%, ' . $purple . ' 100%)',
                    'slug'     => 'yellow-to-purple',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'     => esc_html__( 'Green to yellow', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'gradient' => 'linear-gradient(160deg, ' . $green . ' 0%, ' . $yellow . ' 100%)',
                    'slug'     => 'green-to-yellow',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'     => esc_html__( 'Yellow to green', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'gradient' => 'linear-gradient(160deg, ' . $yellow . ' 0%, ' . $green . ' 100%)',
                    'slug'     => 'yellow-to-green',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'     => esc_html__( 'Red to yellow', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'gradient' => 'linear-gradient(160deg, ' . $red . ' 0%, ' . $yellow . ' 100%)',
                    'slug'     => 'red-to-yellow',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'     => esc_html__( 'Yellow to red', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'gradient' => 'linear-gradient(160deg, ' . $yellow . ' 0%, ' . $red . ' 100%)',
                    'slug'     => 'yellow-to-red',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'     => esc_html__( 'Purple to red', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'gradient' => 'linear-gradient(160deg, ' . $purple . ' 0%, ' . $red . ' 100%)',
                    'slug'     => 'purple-to-red',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'     => esc_html__( 'Red to purple', 'twentytwentyone' ),
                    'gradient' => 'linear-gradient(160deg, ' . $red . ' 0%, ' . $purple . ' 100%)',
                    'slug'     => 'red-to-purple',
                ),
            )
        );

        if ( is_customize_preview() ) {
            require get_template_directory() . '/inc/starter-content.php';
            add_theme_support( 'starter-content', twenty_twenty_one_get_starter_content() );
        }

        add_theme_support( 'responsive-embeds' );

        add_theme_support( 'custom-line-height' );

        add_theme_support( 'experimental-link-color' );

        add_theme_support( 'custom-spacing' );

        add_theme_support( 'custom-units' );

        add_filter( 'rss_widget_feed_link', '__return_false' );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twenty_twenty_one_setup' );

function twenty_twenty_one_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer', 'twentytwentyone' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here to appear in your footer.', 'twentytwentyone' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twenty_twenty_one_widgets_init' );

function twenty_twenty_one_content_width() {
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'twenty_twenty_one_content_width', 750 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twenty_twenty_one_content_width', 0 );

function twenty_twenty_one_scripts() {
    global $is_IE, $wp_scripts;
    if ( $is_IE ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'twenty-twenty-one-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/ie.css', array(), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) );
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'twenty-twenty-one-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) );
    }

    wp_style_add_data( 'twenty-twenty-one-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'twenty-twenty-one-print-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/print.css', array(), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ), 'print' );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    wp_register_script(
        'twenty-twenty-one-ie11-polyfills-asset',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/polyfills.js',
        array(),
        wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ),
        true
    );

    wp_register_script(
        'twenty-twenty-one-ie11-polyfills',
        null,
        array(),
        wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ),
        true
    );
    wp_add_inline_script(
        'twenty-twenty-one-ie11-polyfills',
        wp_get_script_polyfill(
            $wp_scripts,
            array(
                'Element.prototype.matches && Element.prototype.closest && window.NodeList && NodeList.prototype.forEach' => 'twenty-twenty-one-ie11-polyfills-asset',
            )
        )
    );

    if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'twenty-twenty-one-primary-navigation-script',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/primary-navigation.js',
            array( 'twenty-twenty-one-ie11-polyfills' ),
            wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ),
            true
        );
    }

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'twenty-twenty-one-responsive-embeds-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/responsive-embeds.js',
        array( 'twenty-twenty-one-ie11-polyfills' ),
        wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ),
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twenty_twenty_one_scripts' );

function twentytwentyone_block_editor_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwentyone-editor', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/editor.js' ), array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-dom' ), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ), true );
}

add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'twentytwentyone_block_editor_script' );

function twenty_twenty_one_skip_link_focus_fix() {

    if ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) {
        echo '<script>';
        include get_template_directory() . '/assets/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js';
        echo '</script>';
    } else {
        ?>
        <script>
        /(trident|msie)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&document.getElementById&&window.addEventListener&&window.addEventListener("hashchange",(function(){var t,e=location.hash.substring(1);/^[A-z0-9_-]+$/.test(e)&&(t=document.getElementById(e))&&(/^(?:a|select|input|button|textarea)$/i.test(t.tagName)||(t.tabIndex=-1),t.focus())}),!1);
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'twenty_twenty_one_skip_link_focus_fix' );

function twenty_twenty_one_non_latin_languages() {
    $custom_css = twenty_twenty_one_get_non_latin_css( 'front-end' );

    if ( $custom_css ) {
        wp_add_inline_style( 'twenty-twenty-one-style', $custom_css );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twenty_twenty_one_non_latin_languages' );

require get_template_directory() . '/classes/class-twenty-twenty-one-svg-icons.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/classes/class-twenty-twenty-one-custom-colors.php';
new Twenty_Twenty_One_Custom_Colors();

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-functions.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/menu-functions.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/classes/class-twenty-twenty-one-customize.php';
new Twenty_Twenty_One_Customize();

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/block-patterns.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/block-styles.php';

require_once get_template_directory() . '/classes/class-twenty-twenty-one-dark-mode.php';
new Twenty_Twenty_One_Dark_Mode();

function twentytwentyone_customize_preview_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'twentytwentyone-customize-helpers',
        get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/customize-helpers.js' ),
        array(),
        wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ),
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'twentytwentyone-customize-preview',
        get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/customize-preview.js' ),
        array( 'customize-preview', 'customize-selective-refresh', 'jquery', 'twentytwentyone-customize-helpers' ),
        wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ),
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'twentytwentyone_customize_preview_init' );

function twentytwentyone_customize_controls_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'twentytwentyone-customize-helpers',
        get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/customize-helpers.js' ),
        array(),
        wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ),
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwentyone_customize_controls_enqueue_scripts' );

function twentytwentyone_the_html_classes() {
    $classes = apply_filters( 'twentytwentyone_html_classes', '' );
    if ( ! $classes ) {
        return;
    }
    echo 'class="' . esc_attr( $classes ) . '"';
}

function twentytwentyone_add_ie_class() {
    ?>
    <script>
    if ( -1 !== navigator.userAgent.indexOf( 'MSIE' ) || -1 !== navigator.appVersion.indexOf( 'Trident/' ) ) {
        document.body.classList.add( 'is-IE' );
    }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'twentytwentyone_add_ie_class' );
```

Can someone help me out with my little problem? Thanks a ton!

Cheers,

Jakob

Answer (score 0):

it's probably used [gravatar](https://gravatar.com/) website:
go that site and create a account and give email used in wordpress admin panel

Comment: I've already added a Gravatar photo and email but it doesn't seem to help. Thanks for your reply, though!

Answer (score 0):

You can add it just by adding a block for `Post Author` (See the attachment below).

[image]

It will display the Profile image and name of the author of the posy.
This is the default feature in Twenty Twenty One theme.

**UPDATE 1:**

You can add post author to all post/pages just by editing the page/posts template. Here are the steps to do the same:

1. Go to Appearance->Editor
   [image]
2. Click on templates
   [image]
3. Then select Single Post.
4. Edit the template and add Post Author from there to get post author on all posts.
   [image]

**UPDATE 2**

You can also add the same programmatically just by following the given below article:
https://www.wpkube.com/how-to-add-author-box-in-wordpress-posts/

Comment: My bad. I want all the posts pages to feature the image. Not just a single post.

Comment: Can't you add this on pages?

Comment: Yes, but then I'll have to add it to the 300+ posts that I've already uploaded.

Comment: Ohh. Lemee look for a code snippet. If I got any luck will share with you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate the help, Suraj!

Comment: I have just made an edit to my post. Please check and let me know if it helps

Comment: I have also added a link to an article that tells how to add post author details to a post/page programmatically.

Comment: Update 1: Full site editing came with the Twenty Twenty Two theme. I'm using the Twenty Twenty One theme. Thus, full site editing isn't an option :(

Update 2: It's an article that primarily revolves around adding an author box instead of the actual bio. It mentions "inside the loop" but the loop it's referring to is the have_posts loop that has nothing to do with the author bio.

Thanks a ton for the two updates but, unfortunately, I can't use them...